# Host a WCF service from within Apache server?

Tags: wcf, apache

Is it possible to host a WCF Service in Apache?

What are the requirements and how would it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mod_mono and mono-server2 support running the limited subset of WCF that is implemented in mono behind an apache server.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible. WCF web services are built in .NET, while Apache is written in C. Unless you find a third-party module to support this, you're better off hosting your service in IIS.